# get table prefixes for SUB-SITES?

Tags: table

`$wpdb->prefix` returns the main prefix for wp. However, it should return the prefix for sub-blog (when viewing DASHBOARD of sub-blog).

How can i get current blog's table prefix in SUB-BLOG dashboard?
even `get_current_blog_id()` returns incorrect id.

p.s. I use this functions in `admin_init`

Comment: That doesn't happen normally. Please show us your code.

Comment: @toscho, you were right. I have re-checked and found permalinks were messed up and crossing. THANKS!